# how to use a key from a table for two different columns in another table using ef code first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have tow tables with one-to-many relationship.

1. Flights Table
2. Destination Table

I have to use AirportCode  from a Destination table for two columns in Flights table.

1. DepartureAirportCode - column_1
2. ArrivalAirportCode -  c0lumn_2

How to do that by using EF code First?

I have tried with below codes. But That is not correct. I can add  foreign key for only one column.

```
public class Flight
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string DepartureAirportCode { get; set; }   // sholud be foreign key of Destinations_AirportCode

        [Required]
        public string ArrivalAirportCode { get; set; }   // sholud be foreign key of Destinations_AirportCode

        public Destination Airport { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class Destinations
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string AirportCode { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<Flight> Flights { get; set; }
  }
```

DbContext

```
builder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Airport)
                .WithMany(x => x.Flights)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArrivalAirportCode)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);
            
            builder.Entity<Flight>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Airport)
                .WithMany(x => x.Flights)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.DepartureAirportCode)
                .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);
```

**Edit: Added Migration file**

I already have did migration and DB update for add ArrivalAirportCode as a foreignKey.

When I try to add a migration for DepartureAirportCode as a foreign key, I got this

```
 migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Flight_Destinations_ArrivalAirportCode",
                table: "Flight");                
// here dropped FK_Flight_Destinations_ArrivalAirportCode . But not added later. 


            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(   
                name: "FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode",
                table: "Flight");             
 // please ignore above line. Because already I used FK_Flight_Departures_DepartureAirportCode - foreign key from a different table named as Departures. Now I want to use FK_Flight_Destinations_DepartureAirportCode and FK_Flight_Destinations_ArrivalAirportCode from Destinations table


migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Flight_Destinations_DepartureAirportCode",
                table: "Flight",
                column: "DepartureAirportCode",
                principalTable: "Destinations",
                principalColumn: "AirportCode",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);     
// added only FK_Flight_Destinations_DepartureAirportCode. I want two column with  foreign key  FK_Flight_Destinations_DepartureAirportCode and FK_Flight_Destinations_ArrivalAirportCode
```

Comment: Please add the error message you are receiving to your question.

Comment: I have added migration. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use the same properties for two different relationships between `Flight` and `Destination`. Both the `Airport` property on `Flight` and the `Flights` property on `Destination` are used for the "Arrival" relationship as well as for the "Destination" relationshio - and this is not possible with EF.

So in your `Flight` class you are missing a property for the second relationship to `Destination` as you cannot use the same property for Arrival and Depature (because they are different airports):

```
public class Flight
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DepartureAirportCode { get; set; }   // sholud be foreign key of Destinations_AirportCode

    [Required]
    public string ArrivalAirportCode { get; set; }   // sholud be foreign key of Destinations_AirportCode

    public Destination DepartureAirport { get; set; }

    public Destination ArrivalAirport { get; set; }
}
```

And same for `Destination`:

```
public class Destination
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string AirportCode { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Flight> ArrivalFlights { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Flight> DepartureFlights { get; set; }
}
```

once you add it and change your configuration to:

```
builder
    .Entity<Flight>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ArrivalAirport)
    .WithMany(x => x.ArrivalFlights)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArrivalAirportCode)
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);
            
builder.Entity<Flight>()
    .HasOne(x => x.DepartureAirport)
    .WithMany(x => x.DepartureFlights)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.DepartureAirportCode)
    .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.AirportCode);
```

it should work.

Comment: It wont work unfortunately, AirportCode  is not a key

Comment: @Vince you are right `AirportCode` must at least be an alternate key

Comment: @Vince Thank you so much. It's working fine. AirportCode is key of  Destination